# how to apply class on submit button such that it shows the desired submit image

Tags: css, html

i had an image which i want to be displayed instead of submit button. But i don want document.form.submit();
i.e

```
<input type="submit" value="" style="background:url("../images/submit.jpg");">
```

somewhat like this ... but m not getting it :(
so wat m i missing ?? plz help

Comment: Can you use an input with `type=image`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an input type="image" for that.

Otherwise though, try to use single quotes inside the style argument.